# EclipseLink Annotations cannot be resolved

Tags: jpa, annotations, eclipselink

I'm trying to create a simple EclipseLink POC.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to include important, basic classes within the JAR.

For example, the following fails within eclipse (and eclipselink is definitely on the build path): `import javax.persistence.Id`.  Should I have a basic-JPA-functionality jar as well?  Are annotations stored somewhere else within eclipselink (I've looked, can't find anything)?  What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API part is missing. Name of jar is javax.persistence_1.0.0.jar. In EclipseLink 2.4.1 (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/index.php#2.4 Installer zip)  download it is located to eclipselink/jlib/jpa/javax.persistence_1.0.0.jar.